# Understanding the Web services and Enterprise Bean communication architecture.

Tags: java, web-services, ejb, client, jax-ws

I was reading this [enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html). Specifically, this section is confusing to me.

> **Web Service Clients**
>
> A web service client can access a Java EE application in two ways. ***First, the client can access a web service created with JAX-WS.*** (For more information on JAX-WS, see Chapter 19, Building Web Services with JAX-WS.) ***Second, a web service client can invoke the business methods of a stateless session bean.*** Message beans cannot be accessed by web service clients.
>
> Provided that it uses the correct protocols (SOAP, HTTP, WSDL), ***any web service client can access a stateless session bean, whether or not the client is written in the Java programming language.*** The client doesn’t even “know” what technology implements the service: stateless session bean, JAX-WS, or some other technology. In addition, enterprise beans and web components can be clients of web services. This flexibility enables you to integrate Java EE applications with web services.
>
> ***A web service client accesses a stateless session bean through the bean’s web service endpoint implementation class.*** By default, all public methods in the bean class are accessible to web service clients. The @WebMethod annotation may be used to customize the behavior of web service methods. If the @WebMethod annotation is used to decorate the bean class’s methods, only those methods decorated with @WebMethod are exposed to web service clients.

This is what I am getting from the above article context: Highlighted the text with italics. Points bellow are in order of the highlighted sentences in the text above.

1. "First, the client can access ..." Means: Any clients that access the Web Services created with JAX-WS. (Of course, any web service created with any tools/technologies can be accessed by any client.).
2. "Second, a web service..." Means: JAX-WS Web Service can access stateless Session beans.
3. "any web service client can access" How? Can a .NET Web Service client access a Stateless Session Bean? Or I am understanding this incorrectly?
4. "A web service client accesses a stateless session bean ..." I am not getting this. Does it mean A Web Service Client accessing the another web service created using Stateless Session Bean?

Answer (score 0):

In order to your points:

1. The implementation class is not a EJB.

   ```
   @WebService public class MyService {
       @EJB MyBean ejb;
       @WebMethod
       public void doSomething() { ... }
   }
   ```
2. The implementation class is also a EJB.

   ```
   @Stateless @WebService public class MyServiceBean {
       @WebMethod
       public void doSomething() { ... }
   }
   ```
3. .NET client can access to EJB by:

   ```
   @Stateless @WebService public class MyServiceBean {
       @WebMethod
       public void doSomething() { ... }
   }
   ```
4. Explanation of 2. The endpoint implementation class is, e.g., `MyServiceBean`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on each point? I still did not get it. Apologize :-)